# all possible binary strings of length n with bits at specific positions fixed

Tags: c++11, bit-manipulation

I need a fast method to find all binary strings of length `n` which have the bits at `m` positions fixed. A `C++11` compatible function which takes for example an `std:map` with keys the positions of the fixed bits and values the values of the fixed bits. Outputting a vector of `std::bitset<n>`s or `std::vector<n>` would be nice. E.g a function:

```
std::vector< std::bitset<n> > compatible(int n, const std::map<int,bool>& fix)
```

For example if `n=3` and we fix the second bit to 1 then the answer should be

```
{{0,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}}
```

where the order does not matter.

If another data structure is much faster then I prefer speed. Also if significant speed up can be achieved on 64 bit architectures if `n < 50` then that would also be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

There's a fairly simple way with integer math, by looping over the 2<sup>n</sup> possibilities with a special increment that doesn't affect the fixed bits.

That increment is

```
x = (x | isfixed) + 1 & ~isfixed | fixedvalue;
```

The first OR makes the fixed positions 1, which means the carry from the +1 will pass through them. Then the fixed bits are restored to their proper values.

Alternatively, if you have access to `_pdep_u64` or equivalent, you could just use a plain old loop over all the integers from 0 to 2<sup>n-m</sup>, then spread the bits to all the non-fixed positions with `_pdep_u64(i, ~isfixed)`, then fill in the fixed positions.